# Jquery click function doesn't work on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to jquery and am learning it. I was following these 2 tutorials and I couldn't find the solutions for what I am looking for:

1). spyrestudios.com/demos/jquerydemo2/ajax.html

2). web.enavu.com/demos/paginate2/

What I've done :
1). The sub-dynamic content which is data from the whole pagination html ( level 3 )
1). The dynamic content which is a whole pagination html ( level 2 )
2). The main content for handling the dynamic content ( level 1 )

2 problems :

1). When (level 1) is clicked, it shows (level 2) works perfectly on firefox and IE but not on safari.
2). When (level 2) is clicked, Level 3 doesn't work at all.

I've posted a demo page to help you guys understand better :

http://www.thedeanery.com.au/ajax02.html

Any suggestions ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you place the new elements on the page how are your wireing them up?  Are you using the Live jQuery keyword?  This is kinda essential for elements created after the document has loaded.

Comment: Thanks griegs for the reply. I actually used back the on click function. sample codes are :

Comment: $(function(){
  $('p.load_it02 a').click(function(){
   $('#bigcontent').load('maincontent.html');
   return false;
  });
 });